# Why methods to_i and to_f are not appearing in String.methods?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I thought the `#methods` method would list all methods in a class.
Why aren't `to_i` and `to_f` appearing when I type `String.methods.sort`?

`to_i` is supposed to convert a String into an integer and `to_f` -
 convert a string into a float.

```
String.methods.sort
[:!, :!=, :!~, :<, :<=, :<=>, :==, :===, :=~, :>, :>=, :__id__,
:__send__, :allocate, :ancestors, :autoload, :autoload?, :class,
:class_eval, :class_exec, :class_variable_defined?,
:class_variable_get, :class_variable_set, :class_variables, :clone,
:const_defined?, :const_get, :const_missing, :const_set, :constants,
:define_singleton_method, :deprecate_constant, :display, :dup,
:enum_for, :eql?, :equal?, :extend, :freeze, :frozen?, :hash, 
:include, :include?, :included_modules, :inspect, :instance_eval,
:instance_exec, :instance_method, :instance_methods, :instance_of?,
:instance_variable_defined?, :instance_variable_get,
:instance_variable_set, :instance_variables, :is_a?, :itself,
:kind_of?, :method, :method_defined?, :methods, :module_eval, 
:module_exec, :name, :new, :nil?, :object_id, :prepend,
:private_class_method, :private_constant, :private_instance_methods,
:private_method_defined?, :private_methods, 
:protected_instance_methods, :protected_method_defined?, 
:protected_methods, :public_class_method, :public_constant,
:public_instance_method, :public_instance_methods, :public_method,
:public_method_defined?, :public_methods, :public_send,
:remove_class_variable, :remove_instance_variable, :respond_to?,
:send, :singleton_class, :singleton_class?, :singleton_method, 
:singleton_methods, :superclass, :taint, :tainted?, :tap, :to_enum,
:to_s, :trust, :try_convert, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?]
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `Object#methods` lists the methods of the given object.

To list the instance methods of a given class, use `Module#instance_methods`:

```
String.instance_methods.grep /to_i|to_f/ # => [:to_i, :to_f]
```

---

Alternatively, if you have an instance, you can search through its methods:

```
'42'.methods.grep /to_i|to_f/ # => [:to_i, :to_f]
```

Answer (score 0):

What ndn said is true, however I would like to add my 2 cents

```
"3".class
=> String
```

Here the 3 is an instance of String class.

So you got to check instance methods of String

```
String.instance_methods.grep /to_i|to_f/
=> [:to_i, :to_f]
```

When you do `String.methods.sort` you are asking for class methods of String, because String is a class in this context

Comment: `String` is a constant, not “a class,” btw.

Comment: @mudasobwa I don't get you, how come? 'Raj'.class return String. Said that, it must be class,right?

Comment: @RAJ `String` literal itself is a ruby constant, assigned to store a class.

Comment: @mudasobwa How do you know String literal is a ruby constant?  How do I verify this? How do I know it's a constant not a class?

Comment: @RAJ `Kernel.const_get('String')`

Comment: @mudasobwa ah that's a great way!